# bootstrap take full width for select drop down

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

```
<div align="center" class="form-group">

    <select v-model="subject" class="form-control">
      <option v-for="n in papertypes" class="">{{ n.type }}</option>

    </select>
    <br>
```

Bootstrap takes the full width for the select drop down by default.
I want it to be set to get the width what it requires.
How do I  achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can make it possible by giving width for that specific class like

```
<div align="center" class="form-group">
  <select v-model="subject" class="form-control">
    <option v-for="n in papertypes">{{ n.type }}</option>
  </select>
</div>


.form-group select.form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/rvLVBZ) link

Also please notet `align` attribute is deprecated in HTML5. So if you want to align the content to center. Bootstrap has classes for that. Like `text-center` in Bootstrap3, we have `justify-content-center` in Bootstrap4.

Comment: i only made mine `max-width` and everything went perfect! `[+1]`

Answer (score 1):

Add the class `w-auto` to `.form-control`

```
<div align="center" class="form-group">
    <select v-model="subject" class="form-control w-auto">
      <option v-for="n in papertypes" class="">{{ n.type }}</option>
    </select>
    <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add "custom-select" class for select.

```
<div align="center" class="form-group">
<select v-model="subject" class="custom-select">
  <option v-for="n in papertypes" class="">{{ n.type }}</option>
</select>
```